# Drawing and Not enough storage?

Tags: delphi

I want draw a table with Timage canvas but when i want draw a large table, occur this error "not enough storage is available to process this command"

increase the SharedSection in Registry,but not effect at my problem.

please guide me..

Comment: You are going to have to provide a whole lot more details about what you are trying to do to get a decent answer.

Comment: How big an image are you trying to create? (Dimensions and color depth)

Comment: hi, my table size is variable. i create image and set width and height. draw table by canvas.lineto. when draw a large table error occur.

Comment: You can't just say "variable". Of course it will run out of memory at some point. Try to give an example of how big images you're talking about...

Comment: hi ,my code draw sport table.when increase player the competition table become large,for prevent it,decrease table size and i can draw table with 400 player ,it is enough.thank's

Answer (score 3):

I think I've encountered this problem.  Look into the PixelFormat.  Setting it "down" from the default did the trick for me.

WorkPicture1                    := TPicture.Create;

WorkPicture1.Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs if you set the size of het bitmap to something larger than te size of you desktop. To avoid this error you can create a Device Independent bitmap in the following way:

```
bmp := TBitmap.Create;
bmp.HandleType := bmDIB; <-- this does the trick.
bmp.Width := Printer.PageWidth;
bmp.Height := Printer.PageHeight;
```

Whether you need this solution depends on the capabilities of your video card. We had this error a lot in terminal server situations where not much video RAM was allocated to one session. Using this solution you force Delphi to use normal RAM for your bitmap instead of memory on your video card.